# Could not use multiple file upload in Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3

Tags: file-upload, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using `Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3` with `ADF` technology, I am trying to use the `multiple file upload` feature but I could do not find (`Rows`) propriety in `Input file` component that activate this feature.

So, what I am missing?

Is there some extra library need to be add to the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File Upload Enhancements is a feature of `12c`

Check `12c` New Features from `Oracle` website:

[Oracle JDeveloper and Oracle ADF 12c (12.1.2.0.0): New Features](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/1212-nf-1964675.html)